# The V chord in a II-V-I progression in major key

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, jazz, modes

Assume we are in the key of F. Then II = Gm7, V = C7 and of course I = Fmaj7.

If we want to include the 9th in the V chord then we have V = C9 = C E G Bb D. All of those note are in the scale of F major.

The question is **why sometimes in Jazz people play a flat D, that is why they substitute C9 with Cb9?**

Indeed it sounds nice since this b9 note goes nicely into the root but harmonically it is not within the notes of the scale.

Comment: Please ask independent questions separately. I have edited out the second question from this post, but please feel welcome to re-post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question, I guess you're coming from the theory point of view. It's being said more and more. Theory *attempts* to explain what's happening. NOT theory came first, so things ought to fit into its parameters.

If the latter was the case, we'd still be playing early madrigals; Bach, Beethoven, Schonberg, Debussy, et al, would never have emerged. Surely, the main reason we feel that something works is that it sounds good.  It isn't always possible to pigeon-hole particular aspects, even though we seem to be programmed to need it done.

The main 'reasoning' here is that music needs (to us) to resolve, and moving each note in a chord as little as possible is a good way for this to happen. Almost like - you know the sounds you're expecting, but the chord before is so very close, but not quite there. A bit of a tease - dissonance, maybe.

C E G Bb Db. To resolve to F A C E involves C and E staying put, but the E can move one semitone to F. Bb coming down one semitone to A. Db dropping one semitone to C. G moves a whole tone - unless a jazzer would play the F as Fmaj9 ! Very little movement all told, but the blend of penultimate chord notes sounding good.

Comment: I have studied classical harmony so to me some of the "rules" of jazz are completely new. Now, in the specific case I indeed see, as I mention in my question, the Db resolves nicely to the C but I wanted to know if jazz musicians have a more "theoretical" way of thinking this. I see your explanation, and thank you very much. The resolutions I do get them, but constructing tensions like this is quite new to me.

Comment: b9, #9, b5, #5, and combinations thereof, are some of the most used extension note changes (bad phrasing) in jazz, and all create tension that wasn't used much in classical.

Comment: @Marion - Part of what makes this work is the chromatic motion in the line. As Tim mentioned, part of what makes all this work is minimal motion between voices, which creates a smooth transition from chord to chord. In this case, we end up with a chromatic line: D (5th of Gm7); Db (b9 of C7); C (5th of Fmaj7). If there were no b9, D would appear on the C7 as natural 9. The b9 adds increased tension and, therefore, increased resolution. It also "spices things up" a little, which Jazz loves.  There are a lot of differences between Jazz and Classical, so don't hold on too hard to those "rules".

Comment: It's a lot like Chromaticism in Classical theory, where you are looking to create a smooth linear motion as you borrow chords from the parallel key.  If Classical had been using 9s more consistently and earlier on, I suspect that we'd see a lot of this there as well.

Comment: @Basstickler -  tritone substitution works in a similar way, too, as the target chord is preceded by a chord one semitone higher, the tts.

Comment: Tritone substitution? German sixth. Resolves like one too. ;)

Comment: @Tim - TT sub definitely has that quality about it but depending on what extensions/alterations you use on the bII7, it may or may not have as much (or more) chromatic motion.  Like if you keep everything diatonic except the root (b2), then you have an altered dominant, where all the normal voice leading approaches apply, other than the bass note.  If you do change up the chord a little, like a lydian dominant, then you will have more chromatic motion in the chordal accompaniment.

Comment: @Patrx2 - Kinda like a G+6 but functionally a bit different, where the G+6 is a predominant chord and almost always goes to i64 before V.  There is definitely a similarity there but in this case, where the OP is familiar with Classical theory and exploring Jazz theory, I feel the need to make sure that the distinction is made.

Comment: @Basstickler, I was guying a bit, but the functionality is pretty much exactly the same. The reason for I 6/4 with a Ge +6 in CP harmony is to avoid parallel fifths, which isn't necessary in jazz. Augmented sixths make very good dominants otherwise (Fe +6 and It +6 don't need a 6/4 detour). This is a case where I suspect that jazz's harmonic systematisation has lost track of where the function lies, and that's in a modal substitution in the bass (bimodality at a chordal level), and the combination of ascending and descending leading tones. Of course, jazz tends to suspend the former into I M7.

Comment: @Patrx2 - I also thought of the French and Italian +6 and there lack of a need for a cadential 6/4, so to some extent, I think we're into semantics, though I still find the distinction important for the OP just to avoid potential confusion since they're coming from Classical.  In short, I would say that the only real functional difference of an +6 chord beyond the cadential 6/4 would be that an +6 chord is used as a predominant, so you wouldn't find an +6 chord resolving down a half step to the tonic.  I see your point though and remember thinking about that when learning about G+6 and TTS.

Comment: Also, I had to look up "guying".  I'm guessing it's just not something that people use in America as much as elsewhere, though I'm not sure where you reside or learned English.

Comment: @Basstickler, augmented sixths, as predominants, tend to stand in for V of V. The implication of ♭2 in the bass, however, is very modal, which is why they tend to be used as predominants: the bass then acts as ♭6 in the minor mode. If you are willing to accept the modal implications of ♭2, then augmented sixths become excellent dominants, and I've personally used them as such. So... 1) Because the leading tones are used as such, 2) because there is a whole family of chords that all work the same way, and 3) because jazz doesn't eschew the modal implications of the bass (although... <_more_>

Comment: ...it's possible that many players use these implications unconsciously), I'm not inclined to see this as a semantic quibble, but as a situation where someone trained in classical theory might come to an insight that jazz theory alone doesn't provide. The thing about augmented sixths is that the root movement has absolutely no effect on their function - _everything_ is voice leading, and the notation makes that clear. I'll leave it at that, because I'm being prompted to move it to chat. (I'm Canadian, btw - my English sort of straddles the ocean.)

Comment: @Patrx2 - Fair enough. I can't say you're at all wrong. There is definitely value in using your existing knowledge of a similar focus to develop your understanding but in studying both, I have found that many aspects of Classical theory, in a Jazz context, can cause some issues with understanding. A lot of Classical theory just cannot be properly placed in Jazz theory, like avoiding parallel fifths, and a lot of similar things are treated differently, like 13 chords in Jazz compared to a 13th chord in Classical. I definitely think there is value but some amount of distinction is also valuable.

Answer (score 5):

It simply causes a little more tension and gives a bit more payoff for a resolution. Any V7 will want to desperately resolve to I. Adding a ♭9 adds more tension between the root of the V and the ♭9 and gives a bit more weight to the resolution.

On a typical resolution from C9 to FMaj7 you have:

```
C->C
E->E
G->F
Bb->A
D->C
```

On a typical resolution from C♭9 to FMaj7 you have:

```
C->C
E->E
G->F
Bb->A
Db->C
```

The resolution is the exact same to the tonic, but the C♭9 has a slightly shorter distance to resolve back to the C being viewed as a stronger resolution.

As for what to play over it, Mixolydian ♭2 would be fine however with a chord like this you would want a little extra tension so playing just Mixolydian and chromatically going from D to C may yield a rather interesting result.

Comment: Also, since a 7b9 without the root is a diminished chord, all your diminished scales and arpeggios will work nicely, too.

Comment: The dominant chord can resolve to the sub mediant chord as well.

Comment: Yeah, I guess @Dom meant Fmaj7.

Comment: Really don't like the naming. Cb9 used to catch me out in a number I used to play. Was it C (b9) or Cb (9). Context is all very well, but in the middle of sight reading something live, reasoning never came to me!